# Why are colors represented by hexadecimal values in CSS? Is there an historical explanation?

Tags: css, colors, history, convention

In some programming languages, colors are represented by hexadecimal values.  For example, using CSS, to change the text color of a header to maroon-ish, you could type:

```
h1 {
color: #8B1C62;
}
```

I'm wondering what the reason is for using a base-16 numeral system to represent colors.  You could hypothetically use any numeral system to represent the same values, no?

When did this convention start?  Does anybody know where I can read about the history of this phenomenon?

Comment: R = 1 byte, B = 1 byte, G = 1 byte (and sometime sA(lpha) = 1 byte. so convenience.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about speculation, not practical programming problems.

Answer (score 2):

The primary use of hexadecimal notation is a human-friendly representation of binary-coded values in computing and digital electronics.

each hexadecimal digit represent 4 bits. half the byte.
a byte value can be in range of 0 to 255 in decimal but it is more easier to read it as 2 Hexadecimal digit from 00 to FF.

a 6 digit color code hold 256X256X256 combination of red, green and blue ! (8-Bit RGB)

read more about color, color spaces and hexadecimal :

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/10/04/the-code-side-of-color/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly represent colors in any numeral system. Here's what your maroon-ish color looks like in various different systems:

#### Binary: 10001011 00011100 01100010

8 bits each for red, green, and blue. That's nice, but who wants to type all those numbers?

#### Decimal: 9116770

Fewer numbers to type, but how do you manipulate R, G, and B individually? And it feels kind of weird to refer to a color as *nine million, one hundred sixteen thousand, seven hundred seventy*.

#### Hexadecimal: 8B 1C 62

Even fewer numbers to type, *and* we can manipulate R, G, and B easily. Seems like a good candidate for representing colors, but let's try one more.

#### Base-256: ï [^\] b

Nice: we only have to type one character per color component. But I can never remember what number comes after ï or before [the file separator control code](https://www.cs.tut.fi/%7Ejkorpela/chars/c0.html), so I'd have to whip out the ASCII table every time I write or read a color. But what if we wrote the components in decimal instead?

#### Base-256, redux: 139,28,98

Much nicer. Not too many characters to type, and it's very clear which numbers represent R, G, and B.

#### Thus...

The two common ways to represent color values are hexadecimal and base-256-ish, because... it's easy!